# Extending Mvc Music Store Shopping Cart

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I've used Mvc Music Store Shopping Cart in my E-commerce Mvc application. The "Add to cart" function is fine before I added Size attribute in my "Cart" table.

I've 3 products in my products table:

1. "Name:Polo T-shirt , Quantity:40, Price:15, Size:S,M,L"
2. "Name:T-shirt , Quantity:20, Price:10, Size:M,L"
3. "Name:Shirt , Quantity:10, Price:25, Size:XS,M,L"

I've shown these sizes in dropdownlist so the user can select the size and then add to cart.

Problem: When I select size from dropdownlist and hit "Add to cart" button, it doesn't store size in "Cart" table in database.

**View**

```
@model FypStore.Models.Product

@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Size, new SelectList(Model.Size.Split(new char[] { ',' })))
<span>PKR @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Price)</span>
<br />
<br />
<button type="button" class="btn btn-fefault cart">
<i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i>
@Html.ActionLink("Add to cart", "AddToCart", "ShoppingCart", new { id = Model.ProductId }, "")
</button>
```

**Controller** I've used complete shopping cart controller from MVc Music Store Example, so only some part of controller here.

I've added this line **string size = "Small";** and It works fine, It stores "Small" in Size attribute of Cart table. But I want this value to be selected from Dropdownlist.

```
public ActionResult AddToCart(int id)
    {
        // Retrieve the album from the database
        var addedAlbum = storeDB.Products.Single(prod => prod.ProductId == id);
        string size = "Small";
        // Add it to the shopping cart
        var cart = ShoppingCart.GetCart(this.HttpContext);
        cart.AddToCart(addedAlbum, size);

        // Go back to the main store page for more shopping
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

**ShoppingCart.cs**

```
public void AddToCart(Product product, string size)
    {
        // Get the matching cart and album instances
        var cartItem = storeDB.Carts.SingleOrDefault(
            c => c.CartId == ShoppingCartId
            && c.ProductId == product.ProductId);



        if (cartItem == null)
        {
            // Create a new cart item if no cart item exists
            cartItem = new Cart
            {
                ProductId = product.ProductId,
                CartId = ShoppingCartId,
                Count = 1,
                Size = size
            };

            storeDB.Carts.Add(cartItem);
        }
        else
        {
            // If the item does exist in the cart, then add one to the quantity
            cartItem.Count++;
        }

        // Save changes
        storeDB.SaveChanges();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass you dropdown list value to Action method and then you can save them.

```
@Html.ActionLink("Add to cart", "AddToCart", "ShoppingCart", new { id = Model.ProductId }, new {id = Model.ProductId })



@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Size, new SelectList(Model.Size.Split(new char[] { ',' },new { @onchange="SetSize(this.value,'@Model.ProductId')" })))
<script>
function SetSize(size,id)
{
    $(""+id).attr("href", "/ShoppingCart/AddToCart"+"?id="+id+"&size="+size);
}
</script>

public ActionResult AddToCart(int id,string size)
    {
        // Retrieve the album from the database
        var addedAlbum = storeDB.Products.Single(prod => prod.ProductId == id);
        string size = size;
        // Add it to the shopping cart
        var cart = ShoppingCart.GetCart(this.HttpContext);
        cart.AddToCart(addedAlbum, size);

        // Go back to the main store page for more shopping
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, where should i define this Function SetSize ? and how ? I mean this isn't the ActionResult ?

Comment: it is JavaScript function, you can add it in <script></script> tag

Comment: no. Still size is not going in the cart table.

why "id" is written  times ? 
@Html.ActionLink("Add to cart", "AddToCart", "ShoppingCart", new { id = Model.ProductId }, new {id = "@Model.ProductId" })

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96219/discussion-between-ravi-and-umer-waqar).